# error: (-215) reprojectImageTo3D opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am getting an error when I try to use the function reprojectImageTo3D. I have tried two different Q matrices and for both I get the same image. I have checked and the disparity image is properly read.

My code (method 1)

```
disparity = cv2.imread('disparity.png')
f = 2262.52
u0 = 1096.98
v0 = 513.137
tx = 0.209313

q = np.array([
    [1, 0, 0, -u0],
    [0, 1, 0, -v0],
    [0, 0, 0, f],
    [0, 0, -1 / tx, 0]

points = cv2.reprojectImageTo3D(disparity, q)
```

The error I am getting:

```
    OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (stype == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) || stype == (((3) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) || stype == (((4) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) || stype == (((5) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3))) in reprojectImageTo3D, file /io/opencv/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp, line 2747
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tim/PycharmProjects/untitled/Testing.py", line 30, in <module>
    points = cv2.reprojectImageTo3D(disparity, q)
cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp:2747: error: (-215) stype == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) || stype == (((3) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) || stype == (((4) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) || stype == (((5) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) in function reprojectImageTo3D
```

My method 2 is using the camera matrices and the stereoRectify function to get the following Q matrix

```
 Q matrix is 
    [[ 1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -1.09698000e+03]
    [ 0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -5.13137000e+02]
    [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  2.26252000e+03]
    [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -4.77753412e+00  0.00000000e+00]]
```

Running this in the code yields the same error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error basically tells you that the type of the disparity map is not correct. The good thing of Open Source libraries is that if the error is not so clear, you can always go to the source, which in those lines does:

```
CV_Assert( stype == CV_8UC1 || stype == CV_16SC1 ||
           stype == CV_32SC1 || stype == CV_32FC1 );
```

Which is consistent with the [documentation of reprojectImageTo3D](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#reprojectimageto3d) where it states:

> **disparity** – Input single-channel 8-bit unsigned, 16-bit signed, 32-bit
>   signed or 32-bit floating-point disparity image.

Looking at your code you have only one line of code that manipulates your disparity image:

```
disparity = cv2.imread('disparity.png')
```

The [documentation of imread](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread) says that by default, if no flags are passed it will use `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR`.

This means that is will load a `CV_8UC3` unless you say differently. This type is not one of the approved types for this function, thus it fails to execute.

Now, what can you do? It depends, what it is saved in such PNG? 8 bit greyscale image perhaps, then use:

```
disparity = cv2.imread('disparity.png', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE )
```

or perhaps it is a 16 bit greyscale image?

```
disparity = cv2.imread('disparity.png', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH )
```

Then, at least the input will have the correct type.

I hope this helps, if not, please leave a comment.

Comment: Thanks. This helped, had to use flag cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE because of python 3. Ran into other issue now tho, I am not sure how to plot the points that I have obtained to verify that I have created a proper 3D image. I tried mplot3d but I think this is not what I need to use. Got any suggestions?

Comment: I think I am experiencing an issue anyway, since the points matrix consists of +inf and -inf values

Comment: @T.Schoonbeek one question per time :) it is better if you have other issues to open new questions. This way not only I will be able to help but other people as well.  About your questions, maybe the Q matrix is wrong? you may test it with some of the values with the formula [x y z w] = Q * transpose([x y disparity(x,y) w]) and then divide x y z from the result with the w of the result. you may notice the problem if those numbers are wrong (for example a 0 in the w)